# disable button until response VUE

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

Button:

```
<v-button
    class='btn'
    :isLoading='isLoading'
    @click.prevent='sendRequest'
  >
    Search
</v-button>
```

method:

```
sendRequest() {
  this.formatError = false;
  this.$validator.validateAll().then(result => {
    if (result) {
      this.isLoading = true;
      request
        .get('/api/shop/search', { params: { q: this.queryString } })
        .then(res => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          if (res.data) {
            this.$emit('ReceivedResponse', res.data);
          }
        })
        .catch(() => (this.isLoading = false));
    }
  });
}
```

We need to hang disable on the button until we get an answer. (to prevent multiple requests)

I can't figure out how to hang disable.
Right after `sendRequest() {` i need something like `this.BTN = disableTrue` , and when i got answer, in `.then` i need to change `this.BTN = disableFalse`?
But how can I get the button to control disable?

Comment: What is the problem of the above code ? It's do exactly what you want or is there any error ?

Comment: @ArmanGhaffarian The button is not blocked as we would like. Just if you click on it several times, then a lot of responses come from the server. Therefore, I would like to block until the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
    <v-button
       class='btn'
       :disabled='isLoading'
       @click='sendRequest'
  >
    Search
</v-button>
```

Comment: lol, its worked :D thx <3